# What happens when I run out of moderator flags?

Tags: discussion, support, flags, limits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is there a limit on number of posts I can flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78343/why-is-there-a-limit-on-number-of-posts-i-can-flag)

I haven't noticed it before, but recently I found that whenever I flag something for moderator attention, that flag count gets reduced, even though all but one of those was deemed helpful.

Will I not be able to flag any more posts after my flag count hits zero?

Comment: Don't Worry, your flag count will be re-freshed next day.

Comment: @Lucifer Sigh.. thanks.. it's really relaxing. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How many flags do I have?**

When you start out you are alloted 10 flags per-day. This number may increase to up to 100 flags per-day:

- You get one bonus flag per 2000 reputation.
- You are awarded additional bonus flags when you flag correctly.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/flag-posts)

[The amount of flags can be reduced if you flag incorrectly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128912/why-does-my-flag-limit-get-reduced-day-by-day)

Answer (score 1):

It's a daily limit on flags and the number is restored the next day - in UTC.

See [Why is there a limit on number of posts I can flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78343/why-is-there-a-limit-on-number-of-posts-i-can-flag)

Also see **How many flags do I have?** in https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/flag-posts